# How to continue onto the next object in a word list after the nth loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

Sorry for the confusing title, but basically I have two word list files and I want them to print out as show below.

One text file is formatted like this:

```
1
12
123
```

And the other is like this:

```
Test1
Test2
Test3
```

I am trying to achieve this in the end result (printing it out)
so the first file keeps increasing by one (next word in list) and the other word increases one (next word in list) every five times

```
Test1:1
Test2:1
Test3:1
Test4:1
Test5:1
Test6:12
Test7:12
Test8:12
Test9:12
Test10:12
Test11:123
Test12:123
Test13:123
Test14:123
Test15:123
Test16:1234
Etc
Etc
Etc
Etc
```

I have been attempting this for the last hour using:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as f:
   for line in f:
     for word in line.split():
```

But with no luck

Anything helps :)

Comment: What is the logic of your output

Comment: What happens after `Test45:123456789`, does it go `Test46:123456789` with a `0` or a `10` at the end?  Also if you are just generating this strings like so why do you need two text files?

Comment: I am attempting to test a login for a project im working on the "test" would be the account and the "123.." would be the proxies I am using.

Comment: You say you have two files, but your code only shows you opening one file. How could you possibly get results from both files if you only open one of them?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Open both files and for every line in file one print five in file two:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as f1:
    with open('file2.txt', 'r') as f2:
        for line1 in f1:
            i = 0
            for line2 in f2:
                i += 1
                print(line2.rstrip('\n') + ':' + line1.rstrip('\n'))
                if i == 5:
                    break

Test1:1
Test2:1
Test3:1
Test4:1
Test5:1
Test6:12
Test7:12
Test8:12
Test9:12
Test10:12
Test11:123
Test12:123
Test13:123
Test14:123
Test15:123
```

Comment: For the inner loop I'd use `for i, line2 in f2` and put `if i == 4: break` at the end of the block (e.g. after the `print`). As you've written it, this code will exit with a `StopIteration` exception if you reach the end of `f2` before the end of `f1`.

Comment: @Blckknght Indeed. When you say `for i, line2 in f2`, do you mean something as the updated answer?

Comment: Oh, I typed it wrong. I mean `for i, line2 in enumerate(f2)`. Sorry about the confusion.